# Inserting values into a temp table in a stored procedure by reading from XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am working on a stored procedure in SQL Server and as part of it, I am trying to insert values into a table by reading from XML, and then fill one more column using a window function.

```
INSERT INTO #Table (Id, LinkedId, OrderNbr)
    SELECT Id, LinkedId, OrderNbr
    FROM OPENXML (@idoc, 'Request/Details', 2)
         WITH
         (
             Id       BIGINT 'Id',
             LinkedId BIGINT 'LinkedId',
             OrderNbr INT    'OrderNbr'
         )  

--
INSERT INTO #Table (Id, LinkedId, OrderNbr, Rank)
    SELECT 
        Id,
        LinkedId,
        OrderNbr,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY LinkedId ORDER BY OrderNbr) AS Rank
    FROM 
        #Table
```

If the do it this way, my rows are getting repeated with first insert filling `Id, LinkedId, OrderNbr` and `Rank` as null and the second insert repeating the rows of first insert and filling the `Rank` column too. How do I avoid this?

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Advise you not to use `OPENXML` as it is legacy and difficult to use. Better to use `.nodes(@idoc, 'Request/Details')` and `.value` to pull out the data you want

Answer (score 0):

You should combine the queries into a single INSERT, like this:

```
with q as
(
    SELECT Id, LinkedId, OrderNbr
    FROM OPENXML (@idoc, 'Request/Details', 2)
         WITH
         (
             Id       BIGINT 'Id',
             LinkedId BIGINT 'LinkedId',
             OrderNbr INT    'OrderNbr'
         )  
)
INSERT INTO #Table (Id, LinkedId, OrderNbr, Rank)
SELECT 
    Id,
    LinkedId,
    OrderNbr,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY LinkedId ORDER BY OrderNbr) AS Rank
FROM q
```